# pd.concat's 'names' vs 'keys' keywords

Tags: pandas

I'd like to concatenate two unnamed `Series` (they're unnamed because I'm creating them on the fly.)

My first attempt at this was as follows:

```
In [41]: pd.concat([pd.Series([1,2,3]), pd.Series([4,5,6])],
       : names=['foo', 'bar'], axis=1)
Out[41]:
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

I was surprised that this didn't work and read the docs:

> names : list, default None
>
> Names for the levels in the resulting hierarchical index

This doesn't mean much to me on its own.

I tried the less intuitive `keys` keyword, and this did what I thought `names` would do:

```
In [46]: pd.concat([pd.Series([1,2,3]), pd.Series([4,5,6])],
       : keys=['foo', 'bar'], axis=1)
Out[46]:
   foo  bar
0    1    4
1    2    5
2    3    6
```

What is going on here? Why are my column names being specified by a keyword called `keys` and not by the keyword `names`?

Comment: I probably do not know the specific answer to your question, but I do know is that at on-the-fly-creation time, you can specify the name and then it works as you'd expect..  `pd.concat([pd.Series([1,2,3], name='foo'), pd.Series([4,5,6], name='bar')], axis=1)`

Comment: @Uvar really useful. Yes, this does indeed remove the need for me to ask this question! (Although as you say, it doesn't answer it!)

Comment: If concatenation results in the generation of a hierarchical index, then the axes are assigned those names. Otherwise, it is ignored.

Comment: They're semantically different, For names it labels the hierarchical index name, whilst keys labels the index label values. Here there isn't a hierarchical index

Comment: I think @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's comment is probably what is going on here, as you're passing a series and concatenating column-wise, there is no hierarchical index being generated so the names arg is ignored

Comment: @EdChum What do you think about this behaviour? Does it make sense? Maybe the docstring needs a bit of further clarification.

Comment: The docstrings give examples of the result but maybe the param names or description should be clearer as it's not obvious that one names the index levels, and the other the index labels for each level

Answer (score 1):

`Names`  -  Label the index keys you create with the names option. This gives name to the Hierarchical indexing or MultiIndex levels. If the levels are more than one then names are implemented or else they will be ignored.

`Keys` - Add a hierarchical index at the outermost level of the data with the keys option. When you pass a series, index will be set with help of keys. (much like `set index`). After concatenating they will be converted to Dataframe so series index will be set as column name in your case.

When you pass both without using `axis =1` then you can see what labeling heirachial index and adding the heirarhial index mean.

```
pd.concat([pd.Series([1,2,3]), pd.Series([4,5,6])], keys=['foo', 'bar'], names=['Nice', 'TOO'])
```

```
Nice  TOO
foo   0      1
      1      2
      2      3
bar   0      4
      1      5
      2      6
dtype: int64
```

As you can see the levels are named by names parameter where as index is set by keys parameter.